# What is an equation that consists of a proportionality symbol called?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, mathematics, terminology

When I want to refer to an *equation* similar to this image, what term should I use? Is it correct to say "Equation 3", although the *equation* contains a proportionality symbol?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a question for [Math.SE], since it's not about everyday English but technical terminology in a field that's specialized enough that most native speakers not only do not know which to use but can't easily figure out or check.

Comment: This question is about terminology specific to math. Although we may have people who could answer it, none have volunteered an answer. I think the question would get more traction on a different SE site.

Comment: @NathanTuggy  while the language is *mathematical* it's not *esoteric*.  Most students learn about *proportions* and *equations* very early on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use *equation* when you reference this expression.

According to Wikipedia, an [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation) is always a statement of equality. Equality is an example a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation).
Inequality, another relation, has the separate term [inequation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequation) for a statement that describes it - but that term is somewhat uncommon (it is a [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inequation) word but my spell checker is unaware if it).

For the [proportionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)) relation you can use the word *proportion*.

Other relations, such as congruence, membership, inclusion, or orthogonality, don't have specific names for statements describing them.

However, in **technical writing**, an equation is a part of the text that describes a statement in symbolic language, often with a *label* that can be used for reference (such as "equation 1-32"). The statement can be about any relation between things, not necessarily equality. It can also describe inequality, congruence, proportionality, membership, inclusion, orthogonality, and other relations.

If you want to be specific about the kind of relation you can also refer to it with more specific terms. For example, the [Triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) can be written as

```
||x|| + ||y|| > ||x + y||    (1-32)
```

And then you can refer to it as **Equation (1-32)** but also as **Inequation (1-32)**. Note however that most technical writing tools will enforce using the same term in cross references - so I would say using "inqeuation" in technical text is rare.